# Score table with rank variable order and keep rankings

Tags: mysql

Lets say we have a score table from a sport competition:

```
-----------------------------------------
nickname   | challenge |   score   | rank
-----------------------------------------
Sporty     | 3         |   37283   | 1
Performer  | 2         |   32319   | 2
John       | 5         |   21021   | 3
Sandra     | 3         |   12320   | 4
```

The query I use:

```
SELECT nickname, 
challenge, 
score, 
@rank := @rank + 1 AS rank FROM rankings,
(SELECT @rank := 0) r
ORDER BY rank desc
```

I want to reorder all columns but keep the rankinks by score. For example
the table should be ordered by nickname like this:

```
-----------------------------------------
nickname   | challenge |   score   | rank
-----------------------------------------
John       | 5         |   21021   | 3
Performer  | 2         |   32319   | 2
Sandra     | 3         |   12320   | 4
sporty     | 3         |   37283   | 1
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7, so I cannot use the rankings-functionality in MySQL 8.
How can I achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT nickname, challenge, score, rnk
FROM
(
    SELECT nickname, challenge, score, 
           @rank := @rank + 1 AS rnk
    FROM rankings, (SELECT @rank := 0) r
    ORDER BY rnk DESC
) t
ORDER BY nickname;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

The idea here is to first materialize the ranking column inside the subquery.  Then, we can order that by some other column on the outside.  Note that I avoid using the alias `rank`, because starting in MySQL, `RANK` is the name of an analytic function.

Comment: That works fine, thanks. But when i try to add a JOIN in the subquery, the ranking does not work correctly any more.

Comment: Probably you would have to join the subquery itself to the other table, then maybe subquery that (a second time) to do the ordering you want.  If you have another requirement, I suggest asking a new question, this question has been answered.